# ant to maven migration org.aopalliance.aop.AspectException: null

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I am migrating project from ant to maven, If i build and deploy in local Application is deployed successfully but while deploying in stage environment getting below error

```
                                 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.aopalliance.aop.AspectException: null
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:619)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:335)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:165)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:1881)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1174)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:800)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:726)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1059)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:363)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:269)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:320)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.struts.ContextLoaderPlugIn.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoaderPlugIn.java:353)
    at org.springframework.web.struts.ContextLoaderPlugIn.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoaderPlugIn.java:296)
    at org.springframework.web.struts.ContextLoaderPlugIn.init(ContextLoaderPlugIn.java:225)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModulePlugIns(ActionServlet.java:869)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:336)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:256)
```

I check earlier post but not able to resolve the issue

CGLIB version -  2.1.3
Spring Version  - 3.0
Hibernate - 1.0.x

hibernebt.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
          "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<!-- Generated by MyEclipse Hibernate Tools.                   -->
<hibernate-configuration>

<session-factory>
    <property name="use_outer_join">true</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect</property>
    <property name="ConnectionReleaseMode">auto</property>
    <mapping resource="EnrollmentStatus.hbm.xml" /> 
    <mapping resource="programs.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: This is because, your hibernate version and spring hibernate version is not matched. Spring uses Hibernate-3 but you are using hibernate-1.

Comment: But it's working in local

Comment: Where do you deploy your applications?

Comment: local - Tomcat  and stage - websphare unixbox

Comment: Than it is probably due to the you configuration. You must alter your configuration to make it work well with websphare. Could you post your hibernate.cfg.xml?

Comment: <session-factory>
<property name="use_outer_join">true</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect</property>
<property name="ConnectionReleaseMode">auto</property>
<mapping resource="EnrollmentStatus.hbm.xml" /> 
<mapping resource="programs.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>

Comment: Is this your full session hibernate.cfg.xml file? With only this amount of property I really doubt that it will even work on tomcat. Please post your whole hibernate.cfg.xml and update your question.

Comment: Added full config file

Comment: So where is your datasource (connection url, username, password etc)? On normally  you must specify properties for datasource like `hibernate.connection.driver_class`, `hibernate.connection.url ` or `hibernate.connection.datasource`. How your application knows the which database it is using? You can find example hibernate.cfg.xml files from [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-xmlconfig) or [here](https://github.com/bhdrkn/Hibernate-Examples/blob/master/HibernateJPAExample/src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml).

Comment: Could you please post output of  `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose `?